# How to list last 12 months

Tags: php

I want to list 12 months from today. 
Ther's missing a few months ..

```
$i = 12;
while ($i > 0) {
    $ym = date('Y-m', strtotime("-$i month"));
    $yms [$ym] = $ym;

    $i--;
}

print_r($yms);
```

online example: http://codepad.org/XDv4iR3u

Comment: The months are missing because the resulting dates are `2014-05-01`,`2014-03-31`,`2014-03-03`... As to why it doesn't subtract the expected number of days - I don't know. [This bug report](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=27793&edit=3) looks relevant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to provide the current `ym` inside `strtotime`. Consider this example:

```
$yms = array();
$now = date('Y-m');
for($x = 12; $x >= 1; $x--) {
    $ym = date('Y-m', strtotime($now . " -$x month"));
    $yms[$ym] = $ym;
}

echo "<pre>";
print_r($yms);
echo "</pre>";
```

Sample Output:

```
Array
(
    [2013-05] => 2013-05
    [2013-06] => 2013-06
    [2013-07] => 2013-07
    [2013-08] => 2013-08
    [2013-09] => 2013-09
    [2013-10] => 2013-10
    [2013-11] => 2013-11
    [2013-12] => 2013-12
    [2014-01] => 2014-01
    [2014-02] => 2014-02
    [2014-03] => 2014-03
    [2014-04] => 2014-04
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use Datetime and DateInterval

```
<?php
$t = new Datetime();
$interval = new DateInterval("P1M");
for($i=0;$i<12;$i++){
    echo $t->sub($interval)->format('Y-m')."\n";
}
```

https://ideone.com/oQ0FRO

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to to explicitly start from the beginning of the current month.  Since we're currently on the 31st, you'll miss any months which have fewer than 31 days.

```
<?php
$i = 12;
while ($i > 0) {
    $ym = @date('Y-m', strtotime(date('Y-m-01') . " -$i month"));
    $yms [$ym] = $ym;

    $i--;
}

print_r($yms);
?>
```